# Start cmd with pre-loaded string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to know if it is possible to start cmd.exe from a .bat file, having a string pre-loaded but witout executing it immediately.

So effectively what i want to do is to have a bat like the below:

```
cmd /K time
```

but when the user double-clicks on it to just show the:

```
C:\Windows\time
```

but without executing it. I would like the user to press "Enter" to run it.

Is there an option in cmd.exe that allows that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd /k "set /p cmd=C:\Windows\time&time"
```

if this isn't what you were looking for could you please describe what you are trying to accomplish?